# Will Victoria dislike me for settling on another continent?

Tags: civilization-6

The [Civilization wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_(Civ6)) says:

> Victoria's unique agenda is called "Sun Never Sets." She desires expansion to all the continents on the map, likes civilizations on her home continent, and dislikes civilizations on continents where she doesn't have cities.

Does her continent-related relationship to other civilizations take into account capitals only or every city? In my current game, Victoria’s capital is on the same continent as mine. The diplomacy screen shows that I get a positive relationship bonus with her because of being on the same continent. Will that bonus be removed if I settle a city on another continent (where she does not have a city yet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have ever seen when playing against Victoria is that in your particular scenario, you'd have both relationship statuses.

You would get a plus for being on the same continent, but a minus for being on a continent she wouldn't have cities on (yet). So essentially they'd balance out.

When you get further along in espionage or diplomatic view level where you can see exactly what they think, you can see the exact +/- for each particular thing affecting your relationship with her.